How to get only a single row in laravel?
I want a single row of player through his playerNo field which is later added and updated.
I am doing this.
$player = Account::where('playerNo', 99)->get();

Result is many objects of players that only has player object with playerNo, which I do not want because for that I have to use iteration.
foreach($players as $player)
   $player->name = "Samar"


Another option is to use firstWhere
$player = Account::where('playerNo', 99)->first();

is the same as
$player = Account::firstWhere('playerNo', 99);


To get only a single Model returned use first().
eg
$player = Account::where('playerNo', 99)->first();

However if you were getting multiple models by using get() then you have multiple models that match with a  playerNo of 99 which seems odd.

For reference, under the hood, this does take(1)->get(). https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5527e72efe5d86cf83afe21944a47fe9a0bdc406/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php#L342

exactly, like firstWhere()

If you want to get a single row without any specific condition,you can write:
$player = Account::where('playerNo', 99)->first();

But,If you can add other conditions,you can chain other where clauses,for example:
Account::where('playerNo', 99)->where('name' , 'Sadan')->first();

This will return one object.
If you didnt get your answer,leave a comment for me to solve your problem.

it was solved using firstWhere();

You can use the following method to retrieve the first matching record if there are many matching records available in your table:
$player = Account::where('playerNo', 99)->first();

And, If you want to fetch a single record if only a single matched record exists in the table. If more than one matching record exists it the through an exception. you can use sole() method:
$player = Account::where('playerNo', 99)->sole();

following is the example exception:

Illuminate\Database\MultipleRecordsFoundException  2 records were found.

The sole() method retrieves a single record and throws an exception if there is more than one matching record or if none is found. It’s useful when you expect exactly one result.

To get a single row in Laravel you can use first() in controller following way:
$player = Account::where('playerNo', 99)->first();

To get data in blade below:
{{ $player->name }}


This appears to just be a copy of the other answer.
